# Treating nil as zero in sum function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Seller model that has_many Items.

I want to get the total sale price of all of a Seller's items.

In seller.rb I have

```
def total_item_cost 
  items.to_a.sum(&:sale_price)
end
```

This works fine if all the items *have* a sale price.
However, if they haven't been sold yet, `sale_price` is nil and the `total_item_cost` breaks.

In my app, `sale_price` can be either a nil or a zero.

In my `total_item_cost` method, how can I treat `nil` values as zeros?

Comment: Would it not be better to define sale_price as method and make it always return 0? It would be my personal preference, because it keeps all the knowledge about the sale_price where it belongs, intead of spread all over the application in the form of `if sale_price.nil?`.

Comment: It's actually an auction - an item can be 'sold' for 0 (meaning no one wanted it). So nil means it hasn't been auctioned off yet, and zero means it passed. I have other definitions to keep track of this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One way is:

```
items.to_a.sum { |e| e.sale_price.to_i } # or to_f, whatever you are using
```

Methods like `#to_f` and `#to_i` will turn `nil` into `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately ".to_d" (decimal) doesn't work with nils and crashes.  Floats for pricing can lead to inaccurate math.  I ended up putting the columns I needed to sum into an array, then compact (to remove nils) then sum, similar to @dbenhur's answer.

Answer (score 66):

```
items.map(&:sale_price).compact.sum
```

or

```
items.map(&:sale_price).sum(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reject the nil values. `items.to_a.reject{|x| x.sales_price.nil?}.sum(&:sale_price)`

Comment: [`Array#compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) is a more concise way to reject nils.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sales_price is a column in the DB:

```
items.sum(:sales_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# Ruby 2.7+
items.filter_map(&:sale_price).sum
```

Comment: The solution below is preferred if the assumption is valid.  This method loads the item data, instantiates an instance of the model, and then calls the `sales_price` method.  If that method is just returning the value of a DB column, then the process of loading all those records is very inefficient, at least compared to what the DB can do on its own.