# Using variable in .map()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to write a helper that sums using nil values as zeros.  Taking advantage of the following method from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277430/2540204)

```
items.map(&:some_field).sum(&:to_i)
```

The issue is that since I'm writing a helper, `:some_field` will need to be passed in as a variable.  How do I then use that variable in .map?  Something like the following:

```
items.map(&:send(field)).sum(&:to_i)
```

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did `items` come from? If from a single model (something like `Item`), then I'm wondering if you couldn't do `Item.sum(:field)`. You might be able to use `.sum(:field)` even if `items` is coming from different models, but that would take a little more work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could go ahead using following code

```
items.map(&field).sum(&:to_i)
```

Note that i have just removed the "**:**" symbol. Here **field** is your variable

Answer (score 5):

You should simply manually write block passed to `map` method:

```
items.map { |item| item.public_send(field) }.sum(&:to_i)
```

Blocks are closures in Ruby, so if there is `field` local variable in this scope, it will also be accessible inside of block.