# Sum of items in Rails model - Nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add values together from Product model and Service model onto the Order model.  I'll post models below so relationships are clear.   I've tried a variety of options but essentially if I'm adding a Product item and  there's no Service item, it crashes, or visa-versa. Here's message: `` NoMethodError (undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass): ``

I've added `to_i` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276853/treating-nil-as-zero-in-sum-function) to try to turn the Nil into 0 but still no luck.   Where am I going wrong?

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  before_save :update_total
  before_update :update_total
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  def total_service_items
    self.line_items.collect { |item| item.service.price.to_i * item.quantity }.sum
  end

  def total_product_items
    self.line_items.collect { |item| item.product.price.to_i * item.quantity }.sum
  end

  def calculate_total
    total_service_items + total_product_items
  end

  def update_total
    self.total_price = calculate_total
  end    
end
```

Line Items Model

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :service, optional: true
end
```

Service Model

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
end
```

Controller (This controller's `Create` method is being hit in this action)

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController     

  def create
    @order = current_order
    @item = @order.line_items.new(item_params)
    @order.save
  end

      def item_params
        params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity, :service_id, :product_id, :unit_price, :order_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of your associations are likely `nil` — the `optional: true` key indicates that this might be happening.

You can either check to see that these associations are `present?` in your block, or you can assign a `total` to `line_items` which will do this work for you. I'd propose the latter:

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  def total_as_product
    return 0 unless product.present? 
    product.price.to_i * self.quantity
  end 

  def total_as_service
    return 0 unless service.present?
    service.price.to_i * self.quantity
  end 
end
```

And in your Order model:

```
def total_product_items
  self.line_items.collect { |item| item.total_as_product }.sum
end 

def total_service_items
  self.line_items.collect { |item| item.total_as_service }.sum
end
```

Something to keep in mind as you're going along: there are some further optimizations that could be made here — such as [eager-loading your associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) so you don't get hit with some n+1 queries.

Also: `before_update` is redundant when `before_save` is present. You can safely remove `before_update` and get the same behavior.