# Treating nil as zero in sum function for a method-derived attribute (Rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, methods

I have a table that lists rental prices of a product in a table as `number_to_currency(product.heritable_rental_price.to_f * product.quantity.to_f)`, from a Product model, where the percentage is derived from a default and the working value available for that product:

```
def heritable_rental_price
    if rental_price.present?
      return rental_price
    elsif working_value.present?
      return (working_value || 0.0) * heritable_rental_price_percentage / 100
    else  
      return nil
    end
  end
```

I'm using [Treating nil as zero in sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276853/treating-nil-as-zero-in-sum-function) as a model to work this problem out.

```
def rental_price_sum
 self.map(&:heritable_rental_price).compact.sum
end
```

Here's how it plays out in the view:

```
<tr>
<td>
 <% if product.heritable_rental_price.present? %>
  <%= number_to_currency(product.heritable_rental_price.to_f * product.quantity.to_f) %>
 <% else %>  
   --- 
 <%end%>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <% if product.heritable_rental_price.present? %>
    <%= number_to_currency((product.rental_price_sum.to_f * product.quantity.to_f).reduce(0, :+)) %>
  <% else %>  
    --- 
  <%end%>
</td>
</tr>
```

As for things I've also tried, I've been able to get the sum of the pre-defined `:working_value` out by adding .sum[:working_value] to the end of, but not this one, so far (since it's defined in the model, I can't pull it out by `Sym`)

```
Total Working Value: <%=number_to_currency(category.products_by_warehouse_id(params[:id]).sum(:working_value)) %>
```

Comment: Using floating point for prices is not a good idea due to rounding issues. Make sure you use a decimal column. You might also want to use the `COALESCE(column_name, 0)` database function to coerce null values to zero.

Comment: That's the issue- it's _derived_ from a column, not actually one. Otherwise I could sum it using a Symbol.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd point out:

```
elsif working_value.present?
      return (working_value || 0.0) * heritable_rental_price_percentage / 100
```

If `working_value.present?` `working_value` can not be `nil` so the `|| 0.0` never operates.

And if it did, zero times anything, divided by anything, is still zero.

So

```
def heritable_rental_price
  return rental_price if rental_price.present?
  return 0 unless working_value.present?  
  working_value * heritable_rental_price_percentage / 100
end
```

However, I think the main problem is that you are assuming `0.present?` returns `false`, when in fact it returns `true`. I think the check you want is `unless product.heritable_rental_price.nil?`

Also should `return rental_price if rental_price.present?` be `return rental_price unless rental_price.nil?` (if `rental_price` defaults to zero)

Comment: why not just `working_value.to_f` because `nil.to_f #=> 0.0` ? Then this simplifies to `rental_price || (working_value.to_f * heritable_rental_price_percentage / 100)`

Comment: Adding .to_f doesn't negatively affect it - I'm doing that 'downstream' anyhow-  but then how do I pull the sum out from that? I've only been able to do it as a symbol, and :heritable_rental_price is not a valid column. That method is already being used throughout the site from the previous dev right now.